# Adding summary section to roles in CV generated by vitae package R

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

Is there a way to add a summary to `detailed_entries` that does not contain bullets using the `vitae` package? I am able to achieve this using markdown but then lose the tibble formatting for the what/when/with/where/why, and I can't figure out how to combine them.

For example, what I want is something like this (the formatting is a little off since I tried to recreate it in Word):
[image]

Can I use some kind of code like the below to achieve this?

````
---
name: myname
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B, %Y')`"
address: city, state
email: email@hey.com
website: mywebsite.io
output: 
  vitae::awesomecv
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(vitae)
`` ### add extra backtick here!

```{r education}
tribble(
  ~ degree, ~ uni, ~ loc, ~ dates, ~ details,
  "BS in Econometrics", "Some University", "City, State", "Apr. 20XX - Apr. 20XX", 
    list("Something here", "Another thing here", "Another thing here", "Another thing here")
) %>% 
  detailed_entries(degree, dates, uni, loc, details)
`` ### add extra backtick here!
````

Comment: Can you post some code we can knit?

Comment: I added code that can be knitted (need to add the extra backtick to the end of the two r code chunks before running)